# How to read XML file in Java without tagName

Tags: java, xml, nodes, extract

I need to read a file xml in java , the xmd document looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Provider>
       <Invoice>256848</Invoice>
      <InvoiceType>Paper</InvoiceType>
      <Phone>0554334434</Phone>
      <InvoiceDate>20091213</InvoiceDate>   
     <CustomerRequest>
       <Article>
         <ArticleCode>PE4</ArticleCode>
        <ArticleDescription>Pen</ArticleDescription>
        <DeliveryDate>20091231</DeliveryDate>
         <Price>150</Price>
       </Article>
    </CustomerRequest>   
    <CustomerInfo>
      <CustomerID>6901</CustomerID>
      <CustomerAddress> Houghton Street</CustomerAddress>
      <CustomerCity>London</CustomerCity>
   </CustomerInfo>

 </Provider>
```

The problem is that the content of the document can change, by including others tags and many nested tags which can have random level, is there a way to have all tags and values of the document 
in a dynamic way without specifying the tag name?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, read it as a DOM document and you have all the tags and values.

Comment: In fact, almost all techniques for reading such a document (SAX, DOM, other tree models such as JDOM2 and XOM, XPath, XQuery, XSLT) will work without prior knowledge of the vocabulary. The only real exception is JAXB.

Comment: You should Go for `DocumentBuilderFactory `. Also for more details please refer solution 2 from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of that XML is build as a tree, you need to use a recursion:

Assume this is your main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder doc = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = doc.parse(new File("doc.xml"));
    childRecusrsion(document.getDocumentElement());
}
```

And this is the recursion:

```
  public static void childRecusrsion(Node node) {
        // do something with the current node instead of System.out
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes(); //gets the child nodes that you need
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //call the recursion
                childRecusrsion(currentNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, just what i needed!